# How to append bind-attr class to initial one in Ember?

Tags: css, html, ember.js, binding, attr

How to append *dynamic* CSS class to *initial static* one using `{{bind-attr}}`?

When there is a static initial class, dynamic one is not added **on page load**. When I change variable during application run class binding works normally.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/439/) is a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax:

`<p {{bind-attr class=':bold isRed:red'}}>`

See the Ember.js docs [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/#toc_static-classes), specifically where it says:

> Bound class names and static class names cannot be combined.

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuqato/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: It's a pity you cant use *standard* way to define static classes. Nevertheless thank you.